# Setting named path in tsconfig.lib.json of angular 6

Tags: path, angular6, tsconfig

I want to remove relative path from

```
import { ResetPassword } from '../../services/reset-password'
```

to

```
import { ResetPassword } from '@libServices/reset-password'
```

For this i'm doing the following in my tsconfig.lib.json. Base url is inherited from global tsconfig.json as './'

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "paths":{
      "@libServices/*":["commonApp/lib/services/*"]
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

But it is giving compilation error as **could not find module @libServices/reset-password.service**

My project structure is

```
Projects
|- commonApp
   |-src
     |-lib
       |-services
         |-reset-password.services.ts
   |-tsconfig.lib.json
```

I tried a lot using [typescript module documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping). But couldn't get around any solution so far. How can i replace relative paths to named paths using tsconfig in library.

Answer (score 2):

I currently have the same problem and I found [this answer](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/916#issuecomment-425621282) from a member of Angular-CLI:

> That is will make a library not valid as TypeScript will not rewire the paths when emitting, and thus the consumer will not be able to build when using the library and will have this issue. *[...]*
>
> **Paths mappings shouldn’t be used at a library level** *[...]*

So it seems that unfortunately it is not possible for a library.